# Delete from history commits ahead of HEAD

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request, revert

In GitHub, I merged a pull request directly using the web interface. After pulling the merged pull request to my local, I noticed a critical bug in the code. So, I went back to github's website and reverted the pull request. This action generated a new pull request, which I inmediately merged back into master.

### **What I had**:

```
--C1-----C3-------C1'  : master
   \    /  \      /
    -C2-    \    /     : bug-branch
             -C4-      : revert-pull-request-1
```

Where **C1** was the state before merging, **C3** the merging of the branch containing the bug (**C2**), and **C1'** the merging of my revert. Thus, **C1'** has the same code as **C1**.
**C4** was automatically generated by GitHub.

We want all of the commits in our master branch history to be functional copies of our project, so I decided to change history to get **C3** out of the master branch. (My team members agreed on that).

So, I moved the HEAD back twice, and the force pushed it.

### **What I have after moving the HEAD back 2 times**:

```
----C1             : master
     |\
     | -C2         : bug-branch  
     |    \
     |-----C3--C1' : revert-pull-request-1
```

Now I would like to completely get rid of **C1'** and **C3**. But I'm afraid that moving the HEAD again will just mess it up more.

How can I get rid of **C3** and **C1'**?
What happened to **C4**?

### **What I want:**

```
----C1 : master
      \
       C2 : bug-branch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't `revert-pull-request-1` just another branch at this point? Deleting that branch should remove the `C3` and `C1'` commits, leaving you with the history you want.

Comment: I tought I couldn't delete it since the GitHub web interface showed it as "merged". But, actually I could do it and it worked! Moral of the story: prefer to merge your pull requests manually.